# PayPal Chained Payment (money is not going to seconday)

Tags: php, paypal, payment, chained

I'm am making a PayPal Chained payment. I sell ticket(s) for customers and holding a fee of the price of the e-ticket(s). Now I'm testing in sandbox mode, and the money goes to the primary, but not to the secondary. I'm using the suberb php script from angelleye

Here is the payment array, on the primary account i even set up the "API-access" to "paypal-facilitator_api1.wetickets.nl" (i don't know if thats needed)... What am I missing? Thanks for you help!

```
Array
(
    [PayRequestFields] => Array
        (
            [ActionType] => PAY_PRIMARY
            [CancelURL] => http://wetickets.nl/shop/450/mark.html?step=4&amp;action=step4&amp;c=BIP4UWQALFV2JK9ECOVKIZJ65XBLZM
            [CurrencyCode] => EUR
            [FeesPayer] => PRIMARYRECEIVER
            [IPNNotificationURL] => 
            [Memo] => 
            [Pin] => 
            [PreapprovalKey] => 
            [ReturnURL] => http://wetickets.nl/shop/450/mark.html?step=4&amp;action=step4&amp;c=BIP4UWQALFV2JK9ECOVKIZJ65XBLZM
            [ReverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError] => 
            [SenderEmail] => 
            [TrackingID] => 
        )

    [ClientDetailsFields] => Array
        (
            [CustomerID] => 
            [CustomerType] => 
            [GeoLocation] => 
            [Model] => 
            [PartnerName] => 
        )

    [Receivers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Amount] => 11.83
                    [Email] => ontvanger@wetickets.nl
                    [InvoiceID] => #4938-mark
                    [PaymentType] => 
                    [PaymentSubType] => 
                    [Phone] => Array
                        (
                            [CountryCode] => 
                            [PhoneNumber] => 
                            [Extension] => 
                        )

                    [Primary] => TRUE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Amount] => 1
                    [Email] => paypal-facilitator@wetickets.nl
                    [InvoiceID] => #4938-mark-2
                    [PaymentType] => 
                    [PaymentSubType] => 
                    [Phone] => Array
                        (
                            [CountryCode] => 
                            [PhoneNumber] => 
                            [Extension] => 
                        )

                    [Primary] => false
                )

        )

    [SenderIdentifierFields] => Array
        (
            [UseCredentials] => 
        )

    [AccountIdentifierFields] => Array
        (
            [Email] => 
            [Phone] => Array
                (
                    [CountryCode] => 
                    [PhoneNumber] => 
                    [Extension] => 
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [Ack] => Success
    [Build] => 10902368
    [CorrelationID] => 7a97b1666d627
    [Timestamp] => 2014-06-12T10:57:51.419-07:00
    [PayKey] => ---this was the key---
    [PaymentExecStatus] => CREATED
    [RedirectURL] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=--WASTHEKEY---

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAY_PRIMARY does a delayed chained payment, which means the secondary receivers would not get anything until you submit a call to the [ExecutePayment](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/samples/ExecutePayment.php) API.

If you want all of the payments to happen at once then just use PAY instead of PAY_PRIMARY, but then you can still set the primary receiver so that the payer only sees them.